# How to apply php array non index in vb.net

Tags: php, arrays, vb.net, arraylist, multidimensional-array

i want to create array in vb.net like in my .php. 
The code in php like this.

```
$query = ".......";
$query = mssql_query($query );
$data_array = array();
while ($res4 = mssql_fetch_array($query ))
{
        $ms_part_cust = $res4['ms_part_cust'];
        $jmlRows = $res4['jmlRows'];
        $data_array[$ms_part_cust]= $jmlRows;
}
```

so i can call $data_array[$ms_part_cust] in other if i need.
What if in vb.net?

Comment: If my answer **didn't** solve your problem or if you have further questions, please write a comment on my post and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be referring to an [**associative array**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The VB.NET counterpart is a [**`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case it would seem that you need a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`, where both the key and value are strings.

```vb
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

### Adding items to a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`

In order to add new items to a `Dictionary` you must call its [**`Add()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx), specifying the key and its associated value.

```vb
myDict.Add(<key>, <value>)

'Example:
myDict.Add("User", "Visual Vincent")
```

If the specified key is already present in the `Dictionary` an [**`ArgumentException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown, stating that the specified key is already exists.

### Removing items from a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`

Likewise, in order to remove items from a `Dictionary` you call its [**`Remove()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx). **However** this time you only have to specify the **key** of the entry that you want to remove.

```vb
myDict.Remove(<key>)

'Example:
myDict.Remove("User")
'Removes anything with the key "User" (if present).
'For example: {"User", "Visual Vincent"}.
```

### Getting items from a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`

Getting an item from a `Dictionary` works just like in PHP, except for that you use regular parenthesis `()` instead of square brackets `[]`.

Doing this calls the underlying [**`Item` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Dictionary`.

```vb
myDict(<key>)

'Example:
Dim myUser As String = myDict("User")
'Returns, if present, for example "Visual Vincent".
```

If the key you're looking for was not found in the `Dictionary` it'll throw a [**`KeyNotFoundException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Overwriting/setting an existing item in a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`

Overwriting (aka *setting*) an already **existing** item in a `Dictionary` is also done like in PHP, but again using the parenthesis instead of the square brackets.

```vb
myDict(<key>) = <value>

'Example:
myDict("User") = "John Doe"
```

Like above this too calls the underlying `Item` property, and throws a `KeyNotFoundException` if the specified key was not found.

### Iterating a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`

There are two [recommended] ways to iterate a `Dictionary`. You can either:

1. Iterate through every key, then use that to get the value.

   ```vb
   For Each Key As String In myDict.Keys
       Dim Value As String = myDict(Key)

       'Print to console in the format of:
       '    [key] => [value]
       Console.WriteLine(Key & " => " & Value)
   Next
   ```
2. Iterate through every [**`KeyValuePair`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx), containing both the key and value.

   ```vb
   For Each Entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In myDict
       'Print to console in the format of:
       '    [key] => [value]
       Console.WriteLine(Entry.Key & " => " & Entry.Value)
   Next
   ```

### Mimicking PHP

The only way to mimic PHP's behaviour of doing:

```php
$myArray["myKey"] = "myValue"
```

...which either **adds** or **overwrites** an item, is to create a separate method (such as an [**extension method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods)).

The method would have to check if the specified key already exists. If it does then it should ***overwrite*** the value associated with the specified key. If the key **does not** exist, then the method should **add** a new item to the `Dictionary`.

Here's an example of an extension method (needs to be placed in a separate code file, go to `Add > New item... > Module`):

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds a new key/value-pair to the dictionary if the specified key is not present, otherwise overwrites the existing value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Key">The key of the item to add or overwrite in the dictionary.</param>
    ''' <param name="Value">The value to add or overwrite in the dictionary.</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AddOrSet(Of TKey, TValue)(ByVal TargetDictionary As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue), ByVal Key As TKey, ByVal Value As TValue)
        If TargetDictionary.ContainsKey(Key) = True Then
            TargetDictionary(Key) = Value
        Else
            TargetDictionary.Add(Key, Value)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Usage:**

```vb
myDict.AddOrSet(<key>, <value>)

'Example:
myDict.AddOrSet("User", "John Doe")
'Overwrites "User"'s value if the key exists, otherwise adds it as a new item (key/value-pair) to the dictionary.
```

Comment: Thats work. thank you very much. Very detail! Sangat membantu!

Comment: @khamami : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!